# How does Realm handle associations?

Tags: react-native, realm

Are entries in a Realm database unique and referenced?

For example  I have `Person` and `Car` in my schema and a `Person` object can have many `Car`s in a list.

1. I create a new `Person` named "Donald"
2. I create a new `Car` called "Tesla" and I push that new `Car` into Donald's list of cars.
3. If I update Donald's car and change the name to "Tesla Roadster" will I see the changes reflected when I call `realm.objects('Car')[0].name`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relationships between Realm objects are direct references between them. Changing an object in `Person`'s `cars` collection will see the changes reflected in `realm.objects('Car')[0]` because it's the same object underneath.

Check out [Realm Objects & Relationships](https://realm.io/news/threading-deep-dive/#realm-objects--relationships), which goes into more detail.